# How to compare correlation coefficients for two different dependent variables but from same vendor?

Tags: correlation

I am looking at the performance of a certain data vendors in how they accurately track the foot traffic in a store compared to what the store itself says is happening. The higher the correlation, the more accurate the data from the vendor (supposedly). Each score is found by comparing the normalized store data for that specific location to the normalized vendor data for that location.
Here is an example of the original data:

```
        OriginalStore1 | Vendor1 | Vendor2 | Vendor3 | Vendor4
Mon         40         |   22    |    44   |    81   |   42
Tues        22         |   32    |    12   |    18   |   30
Wed         60         |   50    |    41   |    48   |   55
Thurs       37         |   43    |    23   |    35   |   21
```

etc... until Sunday and a similar dataset for Store2. (Please ignore the numbers, I know it's not accurate. Purely for the purpose of giving an example of what I'm looking at)

Here is an example of the final dataset:

```
   Vendor | Store1_score | Store2_score
     1    |      .34     |       .02
     2    |      .43     |       .23
     3    |      .33     |       .72
     4    |      .54     |       .65
```

I want to compare the performance of each vendor. Is it accurate/ok to average the two scores from each store in order to determine the performance of the vendor. If not, what can I do to understand how the vendor are preforming? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Only with strong assumptions. Correlation measures linearity of relationship, not agreement of variables. In any case your own results don’t tempt averaging: e.g. vendor 3 does worst for one store and best for the other. You need the original data: anything else is equivocal evidence.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the response. That makes sense, to move forward, do you have any thoughts on how to approach using the original data to find which vendor performs best? My data is just a table of normalized values for each vendor and store.

Comment: You need to decide how to measure error or discrepancy, and there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calculating and averaging the correlations, I would recommend that you compute few simple metrics for each vendor: total absolute difference; max difference; total absolute squared difference.

The vendor with least total absolute squared difference might be the best fit and closest predictor.

But like Nick said it's ultimately you who needs to decide how to measure error. You may want to penalize being little wrong all the time less than being mostly right but at time being way off in predictions.

I've made the assumption that all the vendor estimates are available for all the stores.